# Drawing a triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, article

[image: This is the triangle I want to draw. I have used GeoGebra to draw this, so in LaTeX I do not want to draw these: "=45°",and the points.]

I want to draw a triangle (with the package TikZ). I don't know how to draw the line, which links the `BC` points. I know I have to use these commands: `+(a,b)`, `++(a,b)`, `(a:b|-c,d)`. Unfortunately I cannot use any of these commands, so please explain, how to use these commands and what do they mean.

*Please, introduce the commands in detail.*  And also, I need the line, which links the points `AB`. I *do not* need the points and the "`=45°`" in my LaTeX document.

Comment: Here you can find a very good user guide with facilities. http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide See *Sections 14.2.1 triangle de Pythagore* and *14.12.1 Colorier un polygone*.

Comment: I'm assuming that @Sigur knows you can read French...

Comment: @cfr, I don't, know. But I informed the section number. It is easy to see the code.

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Comment: What is given to this construction? alpha, gamma (?) and (?)... ?

Answer (score 28):

I probably do not know `tikz` more than you (being a MetaPost user), but out of curiosity I've just consulted the quite elegant tutorial at the beginning [its documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (p. 28-93), and I've come to this result:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[anchor=north]{$A$}
  -- (4,0) node[anchor=north]{$C$}
  -- (4,4) node[anchor=south]{$B$}
  -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This tutorial has probably the answers to most of your questions: a must-read.

Answer (score 9):

After five years ...

- For starting point is used @Franck Pastor nice answer (+1)
- instead nodes are employed coordinates with labels
- added is angle value (using `siunitx`)

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
my angle/.style = {draw, fill=teal!30,
                   angle radius=7mm, 
                   angle eccentricity=1.1, 
                   right, inner sep=1pt,
                   font=\footnotesize} 
                   ]
\draw   (0,0) coordinate[label=below:$A$] (a) --
        (4,0) coordinate[label=below:$C$] (c) --
        (4,4) coordinate[label=above:$B$] (b) -- cycle;
\pic[my angle, "$\alpha=\SI{45}{\degree}$"] {angle = c--a--b};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey how do you size those lines? Are them in cm or inches?

Comment: @SebastianLazalde, default units at drawing are cm. If you like to use other units, than you need to declare them explicitly, for example: `\draw (0pt,opt)  -- (111pt,222pt);`